# Karate unable to set value for json

Tags: testing, karate, web-api-testing

I'm using Karate set value for a payload. One of my test data contains a key name in avro namespace format. For this specific case, I'm unable to set the value

```
* def payload = { "name" : { "com.val.str": ""} }
* set payload.name["com.val.str"] = 'hello'
* print payload
```

Error
`Can only add to an array`

I tried multiple things like

```
* set payload.name[com.val.str] = 'hello'
* set payload.name.["com.val.str"] = 'hello'
```

However, nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `set`, just keep in mind that normal JS expressions work:

```
* def payload = { "name": { "com.val.str": "" } }
* payload.name['com.val.str'] = 'hello'
* match payload == { name: { 'com.val.str': 'hello' } }
```